# How to scrape only contributors from below code using python and beautifulsoup object?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape data from website using python and beautiful soup. I have below HTML code from which I need to scrape only the contributors.

```
<a href="website//contributors">
<span class="num text-emphasized">
  731
</span>
"contributors"
</a>
```

How to scrape 731 which is the contributor's data from this code?. I could not use span and class=" num text-emphasized" since it is not unique to contributors. I need to scrape 731 from this HTML file? Please help?

Comment: Can you give the link to the actual website?

Comment: <a href="website//contributors>

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to help if I can't access the actual HTML. If you give me the URL of the website you are trying to scrape I could look at it.

Comment: Send HTML code or the website link

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML you have given, you can extract `731` as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a href="website//contributors">
<span class="num text-emphasized">
  731
</span>
"contributors"
</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
contributor_data = soup.a.span.get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: Actually, I need to soup from multiple pages on a website. When I go to HTML in the mentioned code. It has graphs and no numbers to scrap data. Like when I try to scrap find_all('span, class ) then it returns multiple rows. How filter based on a class?

Comment: Using span and class am getting a list of 400 elements from which I require only 4th element. How to scrape only 4th element from the list?

Comment: To progress here you need to edit the question in include the code you have so far including the URL so we are able to recreate the problem.